# Mounting SFTP to Files on ChromeOS using Secure Shell App but no files are showing up. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: sftp, google-chrome-os

I've installed the Secure Shell App on my Samsung Chromebook Plus v2 and connected to the server. When I click "connect" it works and I can use the shell app to edit files with vim, but want to use the SFTP mount feature with native Files. I've read that this works, and tried clicking "SFTP Mount" and it prompts for a password. The mount shows up in the files application but there are no files.

Am I missing a step? Does the mount have to be somehow associated with Linux? I have the Linux terminal enabled but want to use this in native ChromeOS. Has anyone successfully done an SFTP mount in ChromeOS? Any tips?

Comment: This extension works for me, but I am unable to use the Caret extension. Instead, it wants me to install separate https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shared-network-folder-sft/gbheifiifcfekkamhepkeogobihicgmn?hl=en

Comment: it works but seems to go to the profile of the user instead of the root.  Not sure how to change that, but trying to figure it out.  If you log in directly instead of mounting, what directory do you drop into?  Does it have files?  I'm guessing it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The default mount point is whatever the server uses which tends to be your homedir.  In the connection dialog, try changing the "Mount Path" to "/" and see if any files are shown.